# How do I delete a Worksheet with VBA that has a date format?

Tags: excel, vba

enter code hereA worksheet will automatically be created. The worksheet will have a date that is entered 2 days from the current date. I am having trouble getting it to delete that worksheet when it becomes 3 days old. Please see my code below for what I currently have.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = Format(Date - 2, "MM-DD-YYYY") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(Date - 2, "MM-DD-YYYY").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Do you want to delete **any** worksheet that is three days old or older? Something to cover weekends and holidays?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning a formatted string into the Sheets collection.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = Format(Date - 2, "MM-DD-YYYY") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(Format(Date - 2, "MM-DD-YYYY")).Delete   '<~~ identified here
        'alternate
        'ws.delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        exit for    '<~~ no point in continuing since only one worksheet could have that name
```

There is actually no point in building the worksheet name twice. If it passes the first name test then `ws` is the worksheet you want to delete.

I started thinking about weekends and holidays that might interfere with the '3 days old' rule. This will delete any worksheet that has a name as a string date three working days old or older.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If cdate(ws.Name) <= APPLICATION.WORKDAY(Date, -3) Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    end if
NEXT WS
```

Comment: It's been there all along but commented out as an alternate method so the OP didn't try to delete the same worksheet twice.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you can try this code:

```
Sub test()
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = Format(Date - 2, "MM-DD-YYYY") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'control the date and delete the sheet 
        If (ws.Name = Format(Date - 2, "MM-DD-YYYY")) Then
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

ex. if today is 01-02-2019 the macro delete the sheet with the date 12-31-2018 (MM-DD-YYYY). If you want delete the sheet 3 days old then you have to change value 2 in 3(within macro).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

## Delete Old Sheets

- This code includes the deletion of possible chart sheets.
- To enable deletion without confirmation you have to set
  `cBlnWithoutConfirmation` to `True`.

### The Code

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Deletes all sheets named by a date in format MM-DD-YYYY
'             that are at least old as specified.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub DeleteOldSheets()

    Const cIntAge As Integer = 3            ' Age of Sheet (Days)
    Const cBlnWithoutConfirmation = False   ' Enable Delete Without Confirmation

    Dim vntDate As Variant                  ' Date Array
    Dim vntSheetDate As Date                ' Sheet Date
    Dim i As Integer                        ' Sheets Counter

    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            With .Sheets(i)
                vntDate = Split(.Name, "-")
                On Error Resume Next
                vntSheetDate = DateSerial(vntDate(2), vntDate(0), vntDate(1))
                If Err Then
                    On Error GoTo 0
                  Else
                    If Date - vntSheetDate + 1 > cIntAge Then
                        If cBlnWithoutConfirmation Then
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                            .Delete
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                          Else
                            .Delete
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```